# The Logic Of Incremental Data on Serial Communication Encoding

Tags: binary-analysis, encryption, serial-communication, encodings

[image: high probability numbers]

These are the serial communication reverse values.
I am trying to understand the logic behind this.
I am pretty sure that 2 bytes represent 1 byte(high byte and low byte), values are correct.

I tried to logical not the values and i realized that there is shifting 2 digits on some digits.

it may be a known encoding method probably.
Can you understand the logic?

[image: reversed values]

Comment: Can you provide more data, ideally 200 msgs? What system is generating this data? Is this being sampled digitally or analog? Is this some sort of remote for opening a garage door?

Comment: I would suggest that the shifted bytes are either plain delimiters, STX ETX characters, or checksums... that should be easy for you to check.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys i have cracked the logic. There is a lookup table. first byte and second byte is logical or'ed and represent the real byte. Here is the look up table

[image]